# How ownership is checked during mutex unlock in kernel?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, mutex

I am trying to understand the internals of mutex implementation in Linux kernel.
According to me, the one of the most fundamental thing about mutex implementation is

> Only the thread that acquired the lock can release the lock on a
>   mutex

Howoever, even after going through the mutex implementation (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/locking/mutex.c), I failed to understand how ownership is checked during mutex_unlock ?

According to the implementation:

```
void __sched mutex_unlock(struct mutex *lock){ 
     .......
     mutex_clear_owner(lock);  // just clears the owner
     __mutex_fastpath_unlock(&lock->count, __mutex_unlock_slowpath);
     ....
}
```

Here is the mutex_clear_owner macro definition(http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/locking/mutex.h#L25).

```
static inline void mutex_clear_owner(struct mutex *lock)
{
    lock->owner = NULL;
}
```

Then how does it check if the thread that has invoked unlock function is actually the thread locked ?

What I am missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To the best of my understanding mutex_clear_owner doesn't check ownership, it clears it. Releasing the lock is performed by a different function (mutex_unlock?).

Comment: yes you are correct. But __mutex_fastpath_unlock also does not perform any operations related to checking the ownership. As the clear_owner is the first statement and clears the owner, any ownership should happen there. As it does not happen there, I fail to understand how the ownership check is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.

"Only the thread that acquired the lock can release the lock on a mutex" is an information for the programmer. Clearly, if mutexes are said to be unlockable only by the thread which locked them, and there is code violating this property by unlocking a mutex locked by a different thread, no amount of error reporting is going to help you and is pointless here.

As such, detection of such violation attempts only makes sense as a debug feature and in such cases an oops/panic is in order.

As you can see, clearing the owner is guraded with #ifndef CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES.

Comment: ok. If I understand you correctly, the information is only for developers and not enforced by Kernel. Thus, if some other thread will try to unlock a mutex that has not acquired it earlier, it will be able to unlock it ?

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what @employee of the month was trying to say.

Here is ownership check debug_mutex_unlock function. This will only be called in debug cases which makes sense.

```
void debug_mutex_unlock(struct mutex *lock)
{
    if (likely(debug_locks)) {
        DEBUG_LOCKS_WARN_ON(lock->magic != lock);

        if (!lock->owner)
            DEBUG_LOCKS_WARN_ON(!lock->owner);
        else
            DEBUG_LOCKS_WARN_ON(lock->owner != current);

        DEBUG_LOCKS_WARN_ON(!lock->wait_list.prev && !lock->wait_list.next);
        mutex_clear_owner(lock);
    }
```